# Tizen: native service not started when launched from a hybrid app

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

There is a Tizen hybrid wearable application: native service and web UI applicatoin.

There is following code to start service from javascript:

```
tizen.application.launchAppControl(
            new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/service"),
            "EFdQkhAQ5b.mydemoappliacation",
            function() {
                console.log("mydemoappliacation service started");
            },
            function(e) {
                console.error("mydemoappliacation failed to start: " + e);
            }
    );
```

Everything works well when launch application on SM Gear device. When launch application on emulator - success callback received in JS code, but service not started (no service "main" function invoked).

In case if deploy service as separate application (not in scope of hybrid app) - service starts normally.

Does anyone have any ideas, why service not started on emulator?

Comment: How did you package your hybrid app ?

Comment: In a web project: Properties -> Tizen Studio -> Package -> Multi -> (set native service checked)

Comment: I did same but in my case it works in emulator and device.

Comment: One thing you may miss .... adding appid of service in web ui project